# Submitting a spark job to a kubernetes cluster using bitnami spark docker image

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, bitnami

I have a local setup with minikube and I'm trying to use `spark-submit` to submit a job to a local Kubernetes. The idea here is to use my local machine's spark-submit to submit to the kubernetes master which will handle creating a spark cluster and taking it down when the work is finished.

I'm using the image `bitnami/spark:3.2.1` and the following command:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://127.0.0.1:52388 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
--conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
--conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
--conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=bitnami/spark:3.2.1 \
--class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaSparkPi \
--name spark-pi \
local:///opt/bitnami/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.2.1.jar
```

This does not seem to work and the logs in the spark driver are:

```
[...]
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to spark-master:7077
[...]
```

and

```
[...]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master
[...]
```

If I use the `docker-image-tool.sh` to build a custom spark docker image with the python bindings and use that, it works perfectly. How is bitnami's image special and why doesn't it recognise that the master in this case is kubernetes?

I also tried using the option `conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://127.0.0.1:7077` when submitting but the error was similar to above.

Answer (score 0):

I recently met a similar issue at [Got "java.net.UnknownHostException: spark-master" in cluster mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76369503/got-java-net-unknownhostexception-spark-master-in-cluster-mode)

```bash
./bin/spark-submit --master k8s://https://127.0.0.1:52388 \
  --deploy-mode cluster \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://your-spark-master-svc:7077
  --conf spark.executor.instances=1 \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=spark \
  --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image=bitnami/spark:3.2.1 \
  --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaSparkPi \
  --name spark-pi \
  local:///opt/bitnami/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.2.1.jar
```

Instead of adding

```bash
--conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://127.0.0.1:7077
```

adding this

```bash
--conf spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://your-spark-master-svc:7077
```

may help.

### Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76370643/2000548